# In Magento, how does one read the exception.log?

Tags: php, magento, exception, stack-trace

I cannot find any documentation on how to read the `exception.log` in Magento; where is the documentation on how to read this?

If there is no documentation in what order are the exceptions printed?

Did #0 happen last or did it happen first?

```
Stack trace:
#0 .../html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 .../html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 .../html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 .../html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('select eav_opti...', Array)
#4 .../html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('select eav_opti...', Array)
#5 .../html/app/code/local/FME/Manufacturers/Model/Observer/Product.php(47): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('select eav_opti...')
#6 .../html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): FME_Manufacturers_Model_Observer_Product->saveTabData(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#7 .../html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(FME_Manufacturers_Model_Observer_Product), 'saveTabData', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#8 .../html/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('catalog_product...', Array)
#9 .../html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(466): Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product...', Array)
#10 .../html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php(548): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_afterSave()
#11 .../html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(319): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product->_afterSave()
#12 .../html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php(714): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#13 .../html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->saveAction()
#14 .../html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('save')
#15 .../html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#16 .../html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#17 .../html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#18 .../html/index.php(91): Mage::run('', 'store')
#19 {main}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zero happened last.

What's happening is that it's going down the list of functions that are failing.
It starts with the actual function that failed and then shows you how it continued to cause other things to fail (this makes it easier to trace a deeper problem if it exists).

Pesach

Answer (score 3):

This is a regular PHP *Exception Stack Trace*; it's *not* specific to Magento.

Line #0 tells us, that the line `110` of the file `lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php` managed to successfully call the method `Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute()`, but then execution of one of the commands of this method resulted in throwing an [`Exception`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php).

Simply spoken, a Stack Trace is just a list of method/function calls, that an application was in the middle of execution of when an Exception was thrown.

Code execution started at #19 `{main}` (bottom of the stack).

- #18, `{main}` was executed until
  method `Mage::run()` was called
  in line `91` of `index.php`
- #17, `Mage::run()` was executed until
  method `Mage_Core_Model_App->run()` was called
  in line `683` of `app/Mage.php`
- :
- #1, `Zend_Db_Statement->execute()` was executed until
  method `Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute()` was called
  in line `300` of `lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php`
- #0, `Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute()` was executed until
  method `Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute()` was called
  in line `110` of `lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php`,
  but some command of this method caused throwing an exception.

As a side note, I wouldn't generally say a stack trace is "going down the list of functions that are failing", like @pzirkind mentioned in his answer.

Because if the method called in #0 (top of the stack) wouldn't have "failed", many of the methods called before *may* still work as expected (and many usually *do*, at least to my experience), or even `catch` the thrown exception.